# How to create a list of objects with one custom object in AutoFixture?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I am using [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) in my unit test, to simplify my test setup. Sometimes I have the use case that I need a list with one specific object.

```cs
var inputValues = AutoFixture.Build<TestObject>().CreateMany().ToList();
inputValues[0] = new TestObject { name = "best guy"}
```

Currently I solve this my issue with the code snipping below. I am sure there is a better solution.

I find this post [Create a list with specific values with Autofixture C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66653510/9533580) but I am really happy this such solution.

I am also aware of something like this:

```cs
var inputValues = AutoFixture.Build<TestObject>().With(c => c.Name = "test" ).CreateMany().ToList();
```

But this will set all list entries with the same value.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered a couple times already on SO. You can see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29272803/2542567) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66313129/2542567).

The best option is to inject the custom object/value into an existing collection. Similar to the first example you provided.

If you really wanted to, you could create a specimen builder that counts the number of times it returned a value and stop after the first one, but really this is not worth the effort. Also your test would be worse because you would make it less obvious for a reader how exactly that unique item is different from the other.

Perhaps if you would provide a more specific example, it would be easier to offer you some advice.